# Setting corelocation results to NSNumber object parameters

Tags: iphone, objective-c

This is a weird one, y'all.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = newLocation.coordinate;
    self.mark.longitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:coordinate.longitude];
    self.mark.latitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:coordinate.latitude];
    NSLog(@"Got %f %f, set %f %f", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude, self.mark.latitude, self.mark.longitude);

    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
    manager.delegate = nil;

    if (self.waitingForLocation) {
        [self completeUpload];
    }
}
```

The `latitude` and `longitude` in that "mark" object are synthesized parameters referring to NSNumber iVars.

In the simulator, my NSLog output for that line in the middle there reads:

```
2010-05-28 15:08:46.938 EverWondr[8375:207] Got 37.331689 -122.030731, set 0.000000 -44213283338325225829852024986561881455984640.000000
```

That's a WHOLE lot further East than 1 Infinite Loop! The numbers are different on the device, but similar--lat is still zero and long is a very unlikely high negative number.

Elsewhere in the controller I'm accepting a button press and uploading a file (an image I just took with the camera) with its geocoding info associated, and I need that `self.waitingForLocation` to inform the CLLocationManager delegate that I already hit that button and once its done its deal, it should go ahead and fire off the upload. Thing is, up in the button-click-receiving method, I test see if CL is finished by testing `self.mark.latitude`, which seems to be getting set zero...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing the pointers to the `NSNumber` objects as `float`s - that is likely to look quite different.

Use:

```
NSLog(@"Got %f %f, set %@ %@", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude, 
      self.mark.latitude, self.mark.longitude);
```

... or:

```
NSLog(@"Got %f %f, set %f %f", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude, 
      [self.mark.latitude doubleValue], [self.mark.longitude doubleValue]);
```